# Python design - cross imports

Tags: python, design-patterns, import

I'm stuck with imports and don't know how to address the issue.

I have 3 modules:

1. `test_project.py`
2. `modules/__init__.py`
3. `r.py`
4. `module.py`
5. `module_configuration.py`

The list of dependencies:

```
test_project.py IMPORTS modules/__init__.py
modules/__init__.py IMPORTS r.py 
r.py IMPORTS > module_configuration.py 
module_configuration.py IMPORTS > modules/__init__.py
```

So as you can see, we have a circular import here.

- `modules/__init__.py` keeps dict of class definitions (class like R).
- `R` class makes instance of ModuleConfiguration in its constructor
- `ModuleConfiguration` needs dict of classes from `modules/__init__.py`.

Error message I get:

```
ERROR: controller.test_project (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: controller.test_project
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 252, in _find_tests
module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 230, in  
_get_module_from_name__import__(name)
File "/media/103AEB9B3AEB7C5A/Projekty/c/svn/tests/controller/test_project.py",    
line 9, in <module>
from c.core.modules import MODULES
File "/media/103AEB9B3AEB7C5A/Projekty/c/svn/tests/../c/core/modules/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from R import R
File "/media/103AEB9B3AEB7C5A/Projekty/c/svn/tests/../c/core/modules/R.py", line  6, in <module>
from c.core.module import Module
File "/media/103AEB9B3AEB7C5A/Projekty/c/svn/tests/../c/core/module.py", line 13, in <module>
from c.core.module_configuration import ModuleConfiguration
File "/media/103AEB9B3AEB7C5A/Projekty/c/svn/tests/../c/core/module_configuration.py", line 7, in <module>
from c.core.modules import MODULES

ImportError: cannot import name MODULES
```

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the instances at module load time, implement functions returning the relevant results and keep these functions in their respective modules. Then once the modules are loaded everything is available to all. 
There's nothing wrong with importing moduleA from moduleB and moduleB from moduleA.
Do you need module global objects that must be created at module load time? This is usually not needed. Instead try to construct whatever module globals are required at first use once all modules are in place.

Comment: Dictionary I'm talking about keeps only class names, not instances. I need it because I pass this list to GUI and GUI makes combo box to select item, every item has it's own class. That is why I need some link between class name and 'key'.

Comment: Just make each module first load whatever other modules it needs and then at the end of the module(s) where it is required, call the method to setup those lists of classes. What is the exact problem you face?

Comment: To setup dict with these class names I actually need it imported. But I think I know what You mean, I can import MODULES in module with class item, and just append this class name to MODULES, so I don't have to import class name in `modules/__init__.py`. Wow, it was so simple, thanks! Sometimes it's just overwhelming me.

Comment: But now these modules are not imported by anything. So when I for example import MODULES in some test it raises an error.

Comment: I don't follow. include the modules you need where you need them. (Or in the beginning of that file.)